# Is there a way to use Socket.io for Private Server-client communication?

Tags: typescript, websocket, socket.io

I am currently working on a project that requires server/client communication, but not with other connected people (a private building game). Anyone know?

Comment: you need to explain what/how exactly doesn't work.
what happens? Do you see an error? What do you expect to happen?

Comment: Removed that part

Comment: You could give each client a separate private key, and encrypt all messages sent to that client via the socket with that key. Others might see the message, but without the key they are useless.